# Is there a way to break NSXMLParser on a condition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

I have a simple question about **nsxmlparser**.

This is my snippet

```
- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters: (NSString *) string{
    [...]
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"openpos"]) {
        if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            // I WOULD EXIT FROM LOOP HERE!
            return;
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

why this *return doesn't work*?
I need to exit from parser method and return back to my class with an error!

I need to force an exception? or there is  a better way to break parser loop?

thanks,
alberto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [parser abortParsing]; before return;

From the docs: If you invoke this method, the delegate, if it implements parser:parseErrorOccurred:, is informed of the cancelled parsing operation.

Comment: In the parseErrorOccured you should test to see what value is getting returned with [parserError code] so that you can handle this separately from other errors if needed.